# parse Json response using angular

Tags: json, angular, parsing

In my ts file I have function which sends some data and then receives json response

```
const fd = new FormData();  
this.service.uploadImage(fd).subscribe(
    (res:any)=>
    {
      console.log(res) ;
```

In this way I get the whole json console.logged.

> {item1: "abcdefg", item2: "xyz"}

But I want to access each component of json seperately.
How can I do that ?

Comment: What exactly you want to do with `res`? Have a look at Angular [JsonPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe)

Comment: I want to console log item1 value for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your console log look like an object not a json, so i don't think you need to parse, you can just access res.item1 to get value one

If it does not work and indeed is a json first parse your string via `const parsedRes = JSON.parse(res)`

Comment: it worked, it's just an object and I just simply access it. But is it ok to use it this way? maybe I should send json instead of it ? what's the best practice ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on the format of JSON response you are getting, but in this particular case, you can do this by `.` operator, like

```
res.item1
res.item2
```